# Persisting lineup changes in online play

Tags: fifa-12

In FIFA 12 I play Online Head to Head Season a lot. Is there a way to make team management changes that won't reset after the match?

For example, I'm always swapping Nuri Sahin into the first 11 of Real Madrid before each match. After the match these changes are gone.

I tried to change it in the *Customize Fifa* section in the main menu, but that did not have any effect on the team when playing in online mode.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do. You have to keep swapping him. I've noticed the same thing when I tried to transfer Ronaldo to MU, he always was in RMA. But that is online only, if you played offline Sahin would be in the first 11.

Comment: Well, transfers are a whole different thing, because it lets you change the strength of the team. But having to reapply lineup, formation and tactic changes for each match is really annoying.

Comment: I agree, haw can somone be expected to change the formation and then change a few players in the allocated time before a game.

Comment: @user18240 There is no time limit for Head to Head Seasons. You make your line-up and formation changes before searching for an opponent.